# How do I save the entire workspace in pandas (like RData)

Tags: python, r, numpy, pandas, hdf

starting in pandas here from R. our production use for R is to save a huge amount of data as .RData (through save_image) to disk and use it the next time we load the workspace. it seems that there is no real solution to save the entire pandas workspace to disk .

there is Dill, but doesnt look like to be production worthy. 
is this an antipattern for Pandas/Numpy? I am thinking that there should be something like HDF5 (or the recently announced Apache Arrow) to snapshot the running state.

Do note that I'm NOT talking about hibernation - I'm just referring to data structures here, not running state of the code or anything like that.

moreover discussion on IRC mention:

- You can use hdf5, but in this case, always roundtrip it before using it, even when it was just computed -- unfortunately, the to_hdf/read_hdf won't necessarily give you the dataframe you started with
- pickle is undebuggable, non-version-compatible, Python-only, insecure-to-unserliazed, and potentially-incorrect-given-the-right-data

so its bad either way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your whole script in a class and then use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to serialize and deserialize that object. It might not work out exactly like the work-space instance in R but it's the nearest thing I can think of right now.